# How to create a dynamic nested mongoose document with the same schema on multiple levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Before everyone tells me I can't call a const before initializing, I do know that.
But I think this is the simplest way to render the concept I have in mind, (**where any subdocument within the replies array also has the same schema as the parent, and documents within the replies array of those subdocuments also having the same schema**). I would really appreciate anyone's input.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   content: String,
   createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
   },
   score: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
   },
   username: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
   },
   parent: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'comment'
   },
   replyingTo: String,
   replies: [commentSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("comment", commentSchema);
```

Comment: Try removing `replies: [commentSchema]` & call `commentSchema.add({ replies: [commentSchema] })`. If that causes an infinite loop, try `const reply = new Schema(); reply.add(commentSchema); commentSchema.add({ replies: [reply] });` [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-add)

Comment: I haven't got the time to write a proper answer but if you want to help people that stumble upon this question in the future, consider writing how you fixed it in an answer to your own question here. After 48 hours pass you can even click the tick to "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a const can't be called before initialization, to fix this issue the parent schema should be called on the children array after initialization the code below:

```js
commentSchema.add({ replies: [commentSchema] })
```

The final result should look like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   content: String,
   createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
   },
   score: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1
   },
   username: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true
   },
   parent: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'comment'
   },
   replyingTo: String,
});
commentSchema.add({ replies: [commentSchema] })
```